# simple modulo not returning list of values I expected

Tags: javascript, modulo

I thought the following would list all numbers from 0 to 21 that are divisible by 7, i.e. 7, 14, and 21. Instead it returns 22. Why?

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 21; i++) {
    if (i % 7 === 0);
}
console.log(i);
```

BTW, I have no programming background and I'm struggling to get my first language under my belt. The teeny tiny details are doing me in. Anyway, thanks for helping me see how placement of console.log affected the result.

Comment: Read your code line by line until you see it.

Answer (score 1):

because you don't print anything in your loop, only the final value of i.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code, reformatted:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 21; i++) 
{
    if (i % 7 === 0)
      ;                // do absolutely nothing
}

// now that i == 22...
console.log(i);
```

what you mean to say:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 21; i++) 
{
   if (i % 7 === 0)
     console.log(i);
}
```